# Boolean results to string value

Tags: java, string, boolean

I need to create a coin tossing java application.

Ok it must have an instance variable boolean.
and when it's true, the side of the coin will heads.
if false, then tails.

how do I go about it?
then after that, head will be = 1 while tails will be 0.

the purpose is to be able to count the number of times each side has.
Thanks!

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Coin {
    boolean coinSide;

    Coin() {
        coinSide = true;
    }

    getCoinside() {
        if(num = 1) {           
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int num = (int)(Math.random() *2); //returns an integer 
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

**Ok I think i better put the requirements document over here so everyone can understand. cheers**

(a) Design, write and test class that will represent a coin, with a method to toss the coin.

A coin has an instance variable that indicates whether a result was heads or tails. What type should this instance variable be?

The constructor for a coin should initialise the face of the coin to heads. The constructor has no parameters.

The coin has two methods:

•   A method to return the result of the toss (i.e. returns the instance variable indicating heads or tails).
•   A method to toss the coin

The method to toss the coin requires a random number, either 0 or 1.

We can get a random number using a method of the Math class. Math.random() returns a double value between 0 and 1. To convert this value to an integer, either 0 or 1, the following code is used

int num = (int)(Math.random() *2); //returns an integer

(b) When you have written your coin class, write a test class, with a main method, which will create a Coin object, and toss it. Each time it is tossed, print out the result (heads or tails).

(c) Now alter the main method to toss the coin 100 times, and count the number of times the coin toss results in heads and the number of time it result in tails. You will need a loop for this, iterating 100 times. Display the heads count and tails count.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please put your code here

Comment: @AntonH i only manage to get a bit done and got confused already.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a solution on a homework assignment. Think about what logic you need to implement to meet the requirements. Then research how you would need to code that ... you will not learn if you do not attempt to do it yourself. Profs aren't stupid, they do check the popular websites for cheaters.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple app such as

```
import java.util.Random;
//This is for flipping the "coin"
public class coins{
private static Random random=new Random();
//This is the coin
private int amountOfHead=0;
//This is the int for amount of heads flipped
private int amountOfTails=0;
//This is the int for the amount of tails flipped
private static int a1;
//This is also the coin
public void flip(){
a1=random.nextInt(1);
//This "flips the coin" making it a 1 or 0
if(a1==0){
  amountOfTails+=1;
  //If the "coin" is 0 tails increases by 1
 }else{
  amountOfHeads+=1;
  //If anything else happens(such as a 1) heads increases by 1
}
System.out.println(amountOfHeads+", "+amountOfTails)
//This prints the results out
}
}
```

To run this program you just call flip().